# Grails named query

Tags: grails, named-query

I have two domain classes, Alpha and Beta.

```
class Beta{
  String betaName
  int age
}

class Alpha{
  String name
  static belongsTo=[creator:Beta]

  static namedQueries = {
    alphaByUser{ param ->
      eq creator.betName,param.betaName
}
    alphaByAge {param -> 
      eq creator.age,param 
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I call for example Alpha.alphaByUser(betaUser).list() I keep getting things like:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'create' on class 'class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass'
```

Or

```
object is not an instance of declaring class
```

I just can't seem to get past it...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your criteria syntax is a bit off.  Try this:

```
static namedQueries = {
    alphaByUser{ param ->
        creator {
            eq 'betName', param.betaName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot tonight! Haven't worked that much with named queries so it was a long shot to begin with :)